# Print lower triangular matrix without using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I want to print the given matrix, which is already in lower triangular ship. I tried to write the code as you can see below. But the result gives me a list of all those elements in one list.I want it to print each row in different line like in matrix form. Any help would be appreciated

```
    L1 = [0, 20, 30, 40]
    L2 = [20, 0, 50, 60]
    L3 = [30, 50, 0, 70]
    L4 = [40, 60, 70, 0]

    distance = [L1, L2, L3, L4]

    mylist = []
    for i in range(len(distance)):
      for j in range(len(distance[i])):
        if i > j:
        mylist.append(distance[i][j])

    print(mylist)
```

This results to 
    [20, 30, 50, 40, 60, 70]

I want it to print
[[20],[30,50],[40,60,70]]

Note: English is my secondary language.So please bare any grammatical mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append slices rather than individual elements:

```
L1 = [0, 20, 30, 40]
L2 = [20, 0, 50, 60]
L3 = [30, 50, 0, 70]
L4 = [40, 60, 70, 0]

distance = [L1, L2, L3, L4]

mylist = []
for i, l in enumerate(distance[1:]):
    mylist.append(l[:i+1])

print(mylist)

# [[20], [30, 50], [40, 60, 70]]
```

Or use a comprehension:

```
[l[:i+1] for i, l in enumerate(distance[1:])]
```

**Edit Based on Comment**

`enumerate` is just a more pythonic way of getting the value and index together. You can use `range()` instead, it's just not as pythonic:

```
for i in range(1, len(distance)):
    mylist.append(distance[i][:i])
```

Comment: `[j[:i] for i,j in enumerate(distance) if i>0]`

Comment: thanks to both, but we have not seen enumerate function yet. so I wish I could have done it without using that function. I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @user3521035 you don't need to use `enumerate` see edit.